# cURL HTTP Code is 404

Tags: php, curl

Example site: http://web.de

in browser: working without any problems

in cURL : gives back error 404 not found.

curl options

```
$cookie_file_path   = "/adm/cookie.txt";


$header[0]          = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,";
$header[0]          .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[]           = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[]           = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[]           = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[]           = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[]           = "Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3";
$header[]           = "Pragma: ";

$ch                 = curl_init();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);


curl_exec($ch);
```

what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Maybe $url is empty??... in this line curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

Comment: No it isn't. When I echo it out it gives me an URL. Also, when I use cURL in terminal it works also

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid url defined in your PHP. It may be that your browser is set up to work through a proxy and curl in your code is not.

Setting $url = "http://web.de"; and running the code, with the last line changed to var_dump( curl_exec($ch)); results in the following being displayed:

```
string(188828) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Wed, 11 Dec 2013 14:05:25 GMT\r\nServer: Apache\r\nX-Frame-Options: deny\r\nExpires: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 11:25:14 GMT\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: private, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, public\r\nVary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding\r\nX-Appserver: hp-webde-bs004\r\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nRTSS: 1-1250-1\r\nContent-Length: 27965\r\nSet-Cookie: SSLB=.1; path=/; domain=.web.de\r\nSet-Cookie: SSID=BgAJEh0O"...
```

So everything seems ok there in your curl code.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Could you also try out https://regalkontrolle.de ? I'm getting a 301 there but cURL doesn't follow the location either. Something's strange is getting on.

Comment: cURL is getting a 301 on that. To make curl follow redirects you need to add: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Answer (score 0):

I made the following test:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    

$raw_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($raw_data);
```

Output:

```
string '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de" data-toolbar-loggedin="false">
<head>
<title>WEB.DE - E-Mail-Adresse kostenlos, FreeMail, De-Mail &amp; Nachrichten</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<link rel="start" href="http://web.de/"/>
<link rel="help" href="https://kundenservice.web.de/"/>
<link rel="copyright" href="http://web.de/Impressum/"/>
'... (length=187595)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the error. These are now my options. completeUrl is the url that checks beforehand if the site needs to has https or http. seems like there are some problems with ssl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $completeUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, getCustomUserAgent());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);`
```