# Can't get BODY from CURL response in PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, http-status-code-404, response

I need to get a PIN code through an API but I can't get the Body of an End-Point response.
The process is very simple and requires no authentication.
Just send the email in the MAILTO field and the webservice returns the pin, or says that the email was not found. In my case below, I just want to receive the Json. But I can't do that.

However, when I test the endpoint in Postman, it works perfectly. But I can't when I try in PHP, even getting the CURL generated by Postman itself.

Here's the PHP code I'm using.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-dev.meucliente.app.br/api/Login/sistema/forgot-pin?mailto=teste@verificando.com.br');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$esposta = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
var_dump($esposta);
?>
```

The above script returns the following result:

```
string(123) "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2022 14:28:51 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Kestrel
```

When I test the same end-point in Postman, the return is correct:

```
[
    {
        "Mensagem": "Email não foi encontrado!!",
        "InnerException": null
    }
]
```

I will be very grateful to whoever helps me.

Comment: Do not set `CURLOPT_HEADER`

Comment: Hi, Marcin. I did what you recommended. But it returned the same result. Thank you.

Comment: Similar / Perhaps related: [Curl_exec returns 404 not found error whereas url is found in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52128826/2943403) and [cURL returns 404 while the page is found in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17476828/2943403) and [File get content or cURL getting 404 page instead of main string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70686390/2943403) and [PHP curl getting 404 while in browser all is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19089349/2943403) and [cURL HTTP Code is 404](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20521125/2943403)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl\_exec returns 404 not found error whereas url is found in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128826/curl-exec-returns-404-not-found-error-whereas-url-is-found-in-browser)

Comment: Hi MickMackusa. I looked into every option you suggested. But none solved my problem. I thank.

Comment: Hi, Markus. I had already analyzed this code. But it didn't solve it. TY

Answer (score 0):

If you get the url corrected, your code should work just fine.
That is if the request should be a GET which is likely.

What you referred to as your response, is not a response. 
It is the response header and you got that only because you have this option:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

The request failed.
Take a look at the first line of the response header.
It returned HTTP status of `404 Not Found`

This is not a valid URL:  `https://api-dev.meucliente.app.br/`

It does not work in postman either.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You did not include your Postman settings and the problem is there. Actually the problem is in your cURL request that does not mimic the Postman request. By default, cURL does `GET` request but the API you talking to apparently expects  `POST` type of request and simply drops all request to that endpoint that do not meet that expectation. If you change your Postman method type to `GET` and try to do the request then you would get no JSON back as well, same you faced with your PHP code.

So if that's the only problem you have, you need to also do `POST` request and to do that just add:

```php
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

to your code and should be good:

```php
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-dev.meucliente.app.br/api/Login/sistema/forgot-pin?mailto=teste@verificando.com.br');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$esposta = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
var_dump($esposta);
```

which would return expected data:

```
string(167) "HTTP/2 400
date: Fri, 25 Nov 2022 05:11:11 GMT
content-type: application/json
server: Kestrel

[{"Mensagem":"Email não foi encontrado!!","InnerException":null}]"
```

BTW: the line

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

is incorrect. You are not outputting plain JSON but just string (as per `var_dump()`) so you should either have it removed, or remove `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);` and replace `var_dump()` with plain `echo`. Or just replace `header()` with `echo '<pre>';` if you test this in browser.

Comment: I believe the request is a GET, which returns JSON.  The header() is to let the receiving Browser know the response is JSON, it has nothing to do with the request.  You are correct about the echo rather than dump. And also about removing the header from the response.

Comment: I do not think there's much to believe. You run the tests and you got the outcome. My answer is based on tests I did using endpoint you provided in your question.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution to the problem. In PHP version 8.0.22, to get the BODY in a CURL request
in the POST model, I also need to send the BODY, even if it is empty.

Here is the script that worked:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-dev.meucliente.app.br/api/Login/sistema/forgot-pin?mailto=teste@verificando.com.br');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{}");
$esposta = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $esposta;
?>
```

Comment: I think you are confusing the request and response with one another.   I believe the request is a GET which returns JSON in the response.

Comment: Hi, Misunderstood. API documentation requires POST.

Comment: I tested on several servers. In all of them it worked correctly, except for the one with version 8.0.22 of PHP. But when I informed BODY, it worked.